# About JavaScript page creation

Tags: javascript

I have a front-end Java script page that take data from user and store it to a variable. My web application is like a Facebook type but a decision support system system using fuzzy logic.

What I want to know is that, will my JavaScript page is shared by all user or a single brand new page is created if a user request a page which uses that JS page?

I want to know because in my JS page I have to store some data globally and it is accessed by different JS function in that same JS page. If a single JS page is shared by all user that concurrency will effect the value in that global variable.

Code:

```
var Data_obj = new Object();   // Global variable

$(document).ready(function () {
    docReady();
});

function docReady() {
    //prevent # links from moving to top
    $('a[href="#"][data-top!=true]').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    //chosen - improves select option
    $('[data-rel="chosen"],[rel="chosen"]').chosen();

    //tabs
    $('#myTab a:first').tab('show');
    $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    });

$('#applicant_table tbody').on("click",".cv_info",function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Cv_path=$(this ).attr("cv_path");
        $("#cv_data").html('<object data="'+Cv_path +'" type="application/pdf" width="450" height="460"></object>');
 $('#myModal_cv').modal('show');
    });

 $('#applicant_table tbody').on("click",".msg",function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Data_obj.E_mail=$(this ).attr("email");//Data fetch and stored in object
        Data_obj.name=$(this ).attr("name");
        $('#myModal_email').modal('show');

     });


 $('#applicant_table tbody').on("click",".setting",function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Data_obj.can_id=$(this ).attr("can_id");
        alert(can_id);
        //$('#myModal_setting').modal('show');
    });
}
$( "#filter_option" ).change(function() {
    $("#applicant_table tbody").empty();
    $( "#filter_option option:selected" ).each(function() 
   {
    var van_id=$("#Job_title option:selected").val();   
        var Duration=$(this).val();
        if(van_id!="")
        {
        //  alert("Anil");
        var Obj=new Object();
            Obj.duration=Duration;
            Obj.van_id=van_id;


              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                url: '/Arsenal/requritment/Update_Application_table',
              contentType: 'application/json',
              data: JSON.stringify(Obj),
             success: function(Data){
                for(var i=0;i<Data.length;i++)
                    {
                    // alert("hello");

                    data=Data[i];
                 if(data.can_id!=null)
                     {var a='<tr><td><b>'+data.apply_date+'</b></td><td><b><i>'+data.name+'</i></b></td><td><b>'+data.phone+'</b></td><td><span class="label-success label label-default">New</span></td><td> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt cv_info" cv_path="/Arsenal/requritment/getCv?can_id='+data.can_id+'"></i>  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope msg" email="'+data.e_mail+'"  name="'+data.name+'" ></i> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog setting" email="'+data.e_mail+'"  can_id="'+data.can_id +'"></i></td></tr>';
$("#applicant_table tbody").append(a);}}}});}});});
function Send_Message()
{
    alert(Data_obj.name);    // data retrieval
       Msg_title=("#title_name").val();
       Msg_body=("#content_info").val();
       $('#myModal_email').modal('hide');
}
```

Comment: Each users sees his own page in his own browser, even if they were all loaded from the same source.

Comment: it means that a global variable in js page will behave like a local variable to that user>>?is it

Comment: Also Data_obj object in my js page belong to single user who loads it not the collection of user who access this serources from my server

Comment: yes, your js code will run in each individual users browser, there is no shared state between users unless you implement this in your server-side code

Comment: Thank you both that  means al ot to me

Answer (score 0):

Every user (each http-request) will load and execute your JavaScript independently ... i.e. your script-content will be 'fresh' for each user.

When you want communication (with your server or other users), you need to send data to backend, and perhaps distribute that, back to all users from your server. Most people use ajax for that, and I see you already have some ajax-calls in the code ... so maybe you do that already. It is hard to tell.

If you don’t want communication between users, you can just store all user-data in local-storage, or keep it in memory.

A more precise answer, needs a more precise question :)